# How do i remove a friend from the database in a self join table?

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-orm

The below is my models.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    birthday = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    friend = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    objects = UserManager()
```

The following works to add a friend.

```
def add_friend(request, friend_id):
    new_friend = User.objects.get(id=friend_id)
    print(new_friend.name)
    current_user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])
    print(current_user.name)
    current_user.friend.add(new_friend)
    current_user.save()
    new_friend.friend.add(current_user)
    return redirect('/friends/')
```

However, i need help removing the friend from a user. The below is what i tried but it does not work. When I check sqllite, the friends are still attached to that user.

```
def remove_friend(request, friend_id):
    remove_friend = User.objects.get(id=friend_id)
    print(remove_friend.name)
    current_user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])
    print(current_user.name)
    current_user.friend.remove(remove_friend)
    current_user.save()
    remove_friend.friend.remove(current_user)
    return redirect('/friends/')
```

Comment: Both methods are named `add_friend` and the contents are almost the same. Where do you attempt to remove the object?

Comment: @Selcuk just updated the second method!

Comment: You only changed the name but it still tries to add, not remove.